# Laravel, Migrations, Foreign Key constraint is incorrectly formed

Tags: php, laravel, foreign-keys, migration

I have two tables, viz. products and institutions. There is one primary key `pid` which auto increments, and one `id` which is a `varchar` of `32` length in both institutions and products.

Every `product` needs to refer to its `institution` therefore I am setting the `institution` column in `products` and want it to be a foreign key referencing the `id` of the institution.

However, I keep getting this error, I have spent the last whole night trying to figure this, without any success.

```
$ php artisan migrate
Migration table created successfully.

   Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table `devbase`.`#sql-824_f23` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed") (SQL: alter table `institutions` add constraint `institutions_id_foreign` foreign key (`id`) references `institution` (`products`) on delete RESTRICT)

  at [...]\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:664
    660|         // If an exception occurs when attempting to run a query, we'll format the error
    661|         // message to include the bindings with SQL, which will make this exception a
    662|         // lot more helpful to the developer instead of just the database's errors.
    663|         catch (Exception $e) {
  > 664|             throw new QueryException(
    665|                 $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
    666|             );
    667|         }
    668|

  Exception trace:

  1   PDOException::("SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table `devbase`.`#sql-824_f23` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")")
      [...]\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:458

  2   PDOStatement::execute()
      [...]\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:458

  Please use the argument -v to see more details.
```

This is the migration for institutions table, the filename is `2018_06_14_165449_create_institutions_table.php`

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('institutions', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('pid');
        $table->string('id', 32)->unique();
        $table->string('shortname', 16)->unique();
        $table->text('fullname');
        $table->string('logo', 100);
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

While, this is the migration for the products table, the filename is `2018_06_15_031837_create_products_table.php`

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::enableForeignKeyConstraints();
    Schema::create('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('pid');
        $table->string('id', 32)->unique();
        $table->string('url', 100)->unique();
        $table->string('shortname', 16)->unique();
        $table->string('institution', 32)->index()->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();

        $table->foreign('institution')
            ->references('institutions')
            ->on('id')
            ->onDelete('RESTRICT');
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$table->foreign('institution')
      ->references('id')
      ->on('institutions')
      ->onDelete('RESTRICT');
```

> Hope it helps.

Comment: this was very `stupid` of me. I should not get high and code. Thank you for your time.